# Prepend div on the right outside corner of a hovering div

Tags: html, css

**What i have**

I have created a scheduler for user tasks. The tasks can be moved using drag and drop. The table has an fixed first column and row.

**The issue**

I am trying to add a **edit**, and delete, **button** when you hover on a task. The edit button needs to be displayed in the right corner, outside the task div.

I have tried to play around with the position property's `display` and `position` in CSS but for some reason i can not get the `prepended div` before the other task on the right.

**Current code:**

```js
// MY HOVER - ADD / REMOVE FUNCTION
$(".drag").hover(
  function () {
    var isAdmin = 1;
    if (isAdmin == 1) {
      $(this).prepend('<div class="test"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></div>');
    }
  },
  function () {
    //this is fired when the mouse hovers out
    $(this).find(".test").remove();
  }
);

$(".drag").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  start: function (e, ui) {
    $(this).data("oldDate", $(this).parent().data("date1"));
  }
});
$("td[data-date1]").droppable({
  drop: function (e, ui) {
    console.log();
    var drag = ui.draggable,
      drop = $(this),
      oldDate = drag.data("oldDate"),
      newDate = drop.data("datum1"),
      dragID = drag.data("userid"),
      dropID = drop.data("userid");
    if (oldDate != newDate || dragID != dropID) {
      $(drag).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(drop);
      var post = true,
        drop = 3;
    } else {
      return $(drag).css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.test {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  top: 0px;
  right: -150px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #FF8E00;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #B5B5B5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.test:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #FF8E00;
}







/* LOCK HEADER AND FIRST COLUMN */
.table td, .table th {
  padding: 5px!important;
}
th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 30;
}
td:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
/* ---------- END (LOCK HEADER AND FIRST COLUMN ) --------- */

.datetimepicker {
  width: 70% !important;
  height: 70% !important;
}

.cal-container {
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
.cal-table {
  position: relative;
  border: solid #ebebeb;
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}
.cal-thead {
  top: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

.cal-viewmonth {
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #fdfdfd;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
.cal-toprow {
  width: 182px;
  min-width: 182px;
  color: #3e5569;
  background-color: #f7f9fb !important;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb !important;
}

.cal-viewmonth,
.cal-toprow {
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}

.cal-userinfo {
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 20px 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.cal-tbody .cal-userinfo {
  min-width: 150px !important;
  text-align: right;
  color: hsla(210, 5%, 40%, 1);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  background: #fdfdfd;
  padding: 0.3em;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

.cal-usersheader {
  height: 20px;
  box-shadow: 20px 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  min-width: 150px !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

.weekend {
  background-color: #b5b5b5;
}
.drag {
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: all-scroll;
}
.span-info {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-draggable-dragging {
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}

.cal-usercounter {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 2px thick red;
}

.cal-userbadge {
  border-radius: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 11px;
}

/* USER TASKS */
.details {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border: 1px solid #ebecee;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.details-uren {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.details-task {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.4;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 94%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <div style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 300px; margin-bottom: 0;">
    <div class="cal-sectionDiv">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead class="cal-thead">
          <tr>
            <th class="cal-viewmonth" id="changemonth">juli 2020</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow">Wednesday 1</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow">Thursday 2</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow">Friday 3</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow weekend">Saturday 4</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow weekend">Sunday 5</th>
             <th class="cal-toprow">Monday 6</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow weekend">Thuesday 7</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow weekend">Wednesday 8</th>
          </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody class="cal-tbody">
          <tr id="u1">
            <td class="cal-userinfo">
              <span><b style="text-decoration: underline">Van Els</b> Numan<span></span></span>
              <div class="cal-usercounter">
                <span class="cal-userbadge badge badge-light">140:13</span><span class="cal-userbadge badge badge-warning">134:36</span>
              </div>
              <div class="cal-userarrows">
                <i class="up mdi mdi-arrow-up-bold"></i><i class="down mdi mdi-arrow-down-bold"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="1/7/2020" data-userid="1">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="13956" data-userid="1" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(81, 255, 0); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #51FF00; color: #000000">Training</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  15:00 - 16:30
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="2/7/2020" data-userid="1">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="13957" data-userid="1" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(121, 32, 32); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #792020; color: #FFFFFF">Day Shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  00:00 - 00:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="3/7/2020" data-userid="1">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="13959" data-userid="1" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(175, 0, 0); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #AF0000; color: #FFFFFF">Sick</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  00:00 - 00:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="weekend ui-droppable" data-date1="4/7/2020" data-userid="1">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="13958" data-userid="1" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(36, 115, 171); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #2473AB; color: #FFFFFF">Late shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  07:30 - 16:30
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="weekend ui-droppable" data-date1="5/7/2020" data-userid="1">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12179" data-userid="1" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(30, 137, 90); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #1E895A; color: #FFFFFF">Vacation</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  00:00 - 00:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="6/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="7/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="8/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="u2">
            <td class="cal-userinfo">
              <span><b style="text-decoration: underline">Henzen</b> Susanna<span></span></span>
              <div class="cal-usercounter">
                <span class="cal-userbadge badge badge-light">140:13</span><span class="cal-userbadge badge badge-warning">134:36</span>
              </div>
              <div class="cal-userarrows">
                <i class="up mdi mdi-arrow-up-bold"></i><i class="down mdi mdi-arrow-down-bold"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="1/7/2020" data-userid="2"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="2/7/2020" data-userid="2">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12326" data-userid="2" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(36, 115, 171); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #2473AB; color: #FFFFFF">Late shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  11:00 - 18:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="3/7/2020" data-userid="2">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="11978" data-userid="2" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(255, 184, 72); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #FFB848; color: #000000">Late shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  17:00 - 00:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="weekend ui-droppable" data-date1="4/7/2020" data-userid="2">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12189" data-userid="2" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(189, 0, 0); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #BD0000; color: #FFFFFF">Extra shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  21:00 - 04:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="weekend ui-droppable" data-date1="5/7/2020" data-userid="2">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12169" data-userid="2" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(30, 137, 90); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #1E895A; color: #FFFFFF">Vacation</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  00:00 - 00:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="6/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="7/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="8/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="u3">
            <td class="cal-userinfo">
              <span><b style="text-decoration: underline">Mak</b> Lokman<span></span></span>
              <div class="cal-usercounter">
                <span class="cal-userbadge badge badge-light">140:13</span><span class="cal-userbadge badge badge-warning">134:36</span>
              </div>
              <div class="cal-userarrows">
                <i class="up mdi mdi-arrow-up-bold"></i><i class="down mdi mdi-arrow-down-bold"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="1/7/2020" data-userid="3">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12938" data-userid="3" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(36, 115, 171); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #2473AB; color: #FFFFFF">Late shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  12:00 - 19:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="2/7/2020" data-userid="3">
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="3/7/2020" data-userid="3">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12266" data-userid="3" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(36, 115, 171); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #2473AB; color: #FFFFFF">Late shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  05:00 - 12:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="weekend ui-droppable" data-date1="4/7/2020" data-userid="3">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12286" data-userid="3" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(36, 115, 171); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #2473AB; color: #FFFFFF">Late shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  07:00 - 14:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="weekend ui-droppable" data-date1="5/7/2020" data-userid="3">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12107" data-userid="3" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(126, 126, 126); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #7E7E7E; color: #FFFFFF">Rest</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  00:00 - 00:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="6/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="7/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="8/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test button has been positioned absolute with css.

```
top: 0px;
right: -24px;
position: absolute;
```

Also the item z-index must be increased so that it is above the other divs while hovering.

Fixed z-index issue? By increasing z-index of th and td:first-child.

```js
// MY HOVER - ADD / REMOVE FUNCTION
$(".drag").hover(
  function () {
    var isAdmin = 1;
    if (isAdmin == 1) {
      $(this).css("z-index", "9999").prepend('<div class="test"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></div>');
    }
  },
  function () {
    //this is fired when the mouse hovers out
    $(this).css("z-index", "0").find(".test").remove();
  }
);

$(".drag").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  start: function (e, ui) {
    $(this).data("oldDate", $(this).parent().data("date1"));
  }
});
$("td[data-date1]").droppable({
  drop: function (e, ui) {
    console.log();
    var drag = ui.draggable,
      drop = $(this),
      oldDate = drag.data("oldDate"),
      newDate = drop.data("datum1"),
      dragID = drag.data("userid"),
      dropID = drop.data("userid");
    if (oldDate != newDate || dragID != dropID) {
      $(drag).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(drop);
      var post = true,
        drop = 3;
    } else {
      return $(drag).css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.test {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  top: 0px;
  right: -24px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #FF8E00;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #B5B5B5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.test:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #FF8E00;
}







/* LOCK HEADER AND FIRST COLUMN */
.table td, .table th {
  padding: 5px!important;
}
th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10030;
}
td:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10010;
}
thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10020;
}
/* ---------- END (LOCK HEADER AND FIRST COLUMN ) --------- */

.datetimepicker {
  width: 70% !important;
  height: 70% !important;
}

.cal-container {
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
.cal-table {
  position: relative;
  border: solid #ebebeb;
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}
.cal-thead {
  top: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

.cal-viewmonth {
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #fdfdfd;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
.cal-toprow {
  width: 182px;
  min-width: 182px;
  color: #3e5569;
  background-color: #f7f9fb !important;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb !important;
}

.cal-viewmonth,
.cal-toprow {
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}

.cal-userinfo {
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 20px 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.cal-tbody .cal-userinfo {
  min-width: 150px !important;
  text-align: right;
  color: hsla(210, 5%, 40%, 1);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  background: #fdfdfd;
  padding: 0.3em;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

.cal-usersheader {
  height: 20px;
  box-shadow: 20px 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  min-width: 150px !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

.weekend {
  background-color: #b5b5b5;
}
.drag {
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: all-scroll;
}
.span-info {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-draggable-dragging {
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}

.cal-usercounter {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 2px thick red;
}

.cal-userbadge {
  border-radius: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 11px;
}

/* USER TASKS */
.details {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border: 1px solid #ebecee;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.details-uren {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.details-task {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.4;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 94%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <div style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 300px; margin-bottom: 0;">
    <div class="cal-sectionDiv">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead class="cal-thead">
          <tr>
            <th class="cal-viewmonth" id="changemonth">juli 2020</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow">Wednesday 1</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow">Thursday 2</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow">Friday 3</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow weekend">Saturday 4</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow weekend">Sunday 5</th>
             <th class="cal-toprow">Monday 6</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow weekend">Thuesday 7</th>
            <th class="cal-toprow weekend">Wednesday 8</th>
          </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody class="cal-tbody">
          <tr id="u1">
            <td class="cal-userinfo">
              <span><b style="text-decoration: underline">Van Els</b> Numan<span></span></span>
              <div class="cal-usercounter">
                <span class="cal-userbadge badge badge-light">140:13</span><span class="cal-userbadge badge badge-warning">134:36</span>
              </div>
              <div class="cal-userarrows">
                <i class="up mdi mdi-arrow-up-bold"></i><i class="down mdi mdi-arrow-down-bold"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="1/7/2020" data-userid="1">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="13956" data-userid="1" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(81, 255, 0); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #51FF00; color: #000000">Training</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  15:00 - 16:30
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="2/7/2020" data-userid="1">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="13957" data-userid="1" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(121, 32, 32); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #792020; color: #FFFFFF">Day Shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  00:00 - 00:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="3/7/2020" data-userid="1">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="13959" data-userid="1" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(175, 0, 0); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #AF0000; color: #FFFFFF">Sick</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  00:00 - 00:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="weekend ui-droppable" data-date1="4/7/2020" data-userid="1">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="13958" data-userid="1" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(36, 115, 171); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #2473AB; color: #FFFFFF">Late shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  07:30 - 16:30
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="weekend ui-droppable" data-date1="5/7/2020" data-userid="1">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12179" data-userid="1" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(30, 137, 90); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #1E895A; color: #FFFFFF">Vacation</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  00:00 - 00:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="6/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="7/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="8/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="u2">
            <td class="cal-userinfo">
              <span><b style="text-decoration: underline">Henzen</b> Susanna<span></span></span>
              <div class="cal-usercounter">
                <span class="cal-userbadge badge badge-light">140:13</span><span class="cal-userbadge badge badge-warning">134:36</span>
              </div>
              <div class="cal-userarrows">
                <i class="up mdi mdi-arrow-up-bold"></i><i class="down mdi mdi-arrow-down-bold"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="1/7/2020" data-userid="2"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="2/7/2020" data-userid="2">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12326" data-userid="2" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(36, 115, 171); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #2473AB; color: #FFFFFF">Late shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  11:00 - 18:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="3/7/2020" data-userid="2">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="11978" data-userid="2" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(255, 184, 72); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #FFB848; color: #000000">Late shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  17:00 - 00:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="weekend ui-droppable" data-date1="4/7/2020" data-userid="2">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12189" data-userid="2" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(189, 0, 0); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #BD0000; color: #FFFFFF">Extra shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  21:00 - 04:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="weekend ui-droppable" data-date1="5/7/2020" data-userid="2">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12169" data-userid="2" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(30, 137, 90); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #1E895A; color: #FFFFFF">Vacation</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  00:00 - 00:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="6/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="7/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="8/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="u3">
            <td class="cal-userinfo">
              <span><b style="text-decoration: underline">Mak</b> Lokman<span></span></span>
              <div class="cal-usercounter">
                <span class="cal-userbadge badge badge-light">140:13</span><span class="cal-userbadge badge badge-warning">134:36</span>
              </div>
              <div class="cal-userarrows">
                <i class="up mdi mdi-arrow-up-bold"></i><i class="down mdi mdi-arrow-down-bold"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="1/7/2020" data-userid="3">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12938" data-userid="3" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(36, 115, 171); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #2473AB; color: #FFFFFF">Late shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  12:00 - 19:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="2/7/2020" data-userid="3">
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="3/7/2020" data-userid="3">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12266" data-userid="3" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(36, 115, 171); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #2473AB; color: #FFFFFF">Late shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  05:00 - 12:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="weekend ui-droppable" data-date1="4/7/2020" data-userid="3">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12286" data-userid="3" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(36, 115, 171); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #2473AB; color: #FFFFFF">Late shift</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  07:00 - 14:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="weekend ui-droppable" data-date1="5/7/2020" data-userid="3">
              <div class="drag details ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-taskid="12107" data-userid="3" style="border-left: 5px solid rgb(126, 126, 126); position: relative;">
                <h3 class="details-task" style=" background: #7E7E7E; color: #FFFFFF">Rest</h3>
                <div class="details-uren">
                  00:00 - 00:00
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="6/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="7/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
            <td class="ui-droppable" data-date1="8/7/2020" data-userid="1"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i want to have to edit button outside the "task" div. You have placed it inside now.

Comment: I have updated the answer, maybe sketch what you need if that is not correct.

Comment: The edit button is positioned correctly now, but when hovering a task the button will go in front of the first row now. The first row and column should stay absolute

Comment: Your question doesn't mention that as a problem.

Comment: To restrict a drag area you need to set the containment option of draggable which can be an element or an array of bounding values.

Comment: Thats true because its not an issue with the code i have. The task need to stay under the left row and top column. The Edit icon needs to be on the right side (outside task div). So when you use the scroll-bars the task is not allowed to go before the top column of the left row when hovering this task

Comment: Not sure I understand, the code I posted behaves the same way as yours for where you can drag the task item.

Comment: I have displayed the difference in our coding (https://i.imgur.com/e3RHmdP.jpg) I am looking to alter your code to stay under the top and left bar. When i find a solution ill accept this as an answer.

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? It's behaving differently for me.

Comment: Windows/ Firefox, Chrome and Edge display this issue

Comment: I think it's fixed as you want it now but I don't have windows to test it on.